# Force older commits to merge as if they were newer commits

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Something went really wrong with our git. A few of our commits disappeared, which (of course) we then committed on top of. **We were able to get the missing commits back into our system**, but in doing that we **overrode the more recent commits**.

I have the more recent commits in a branch on my computer, which is still missing the vanishing commits. **I want to get the missing commits back into my branch via a merge as if they were newer commits, and then commit the newer changes back to the origin.** Of course, when I try to pull as I normally would, git thinks that origin is fully integrated into my local branch, since my local branch was fully integrated into before we recovered the lost commits.

Is there any way to do this? Any alternative solutions?

I'm pretty new to git, so excuse the lack of proper terminology

Comment: We can probably fix this for you, probably using some combination of rebase and the reflog. However, we need more info. Can you please include some `git log --graph --oneline --decorate <branch1> <branch2>` output into your question? You can remove sensitive commit messages if you want. Also, please make it clear which branches/commits have been pushed to a public, shared repo, and which ones have not. Using rebase is going to involve rewriting history, which your coworkers may have trouble dealing with.

Comment: I tried using rebasing as you suggested, that might have been an option but when I tried something got messed up with the files and I couldn't get it done all the way. Cherry-picking worked and was easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main command to use here would be [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

It allows you to cherry-pick one (or several) commit(s), and apply them on your current branch.

The commit date will change.

If you have both branches in the same repo, you can use that command directly.

If not, you can:

- add the repo where you have the more recent commit as a remote:

  ```
  git remote add newcommits /url/to/repo/with/more/recent/commits
  ```
- cherry-pick from that remote repo

  ```
  git fetch newcommits 
  git cherry-pick <new commits SHA1>
  git cherry-pick <new commits SHA1>
  ```

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Cherry-picking is a pretty neat feature, good to know about it in general!